# Finding word in a sentence

Tags: excel, vba

I'm finding a word in a cell which has sentence, both sentence & the word to be found may have space/special character.

But the function or macro should ignore them & match it if the word exits given below is the example.

```html
Column1          Column2            Result Expected Result
Spider-Man      SpiderMan 56        TRUE     TRUE
6x              6x25                TRUE     TRUE
jesse james     jesse/james            TRUE     TRUE
13.3"         133 hd                FALSE TRUE
15.6"         5517 156 ccfl        FALSE TRUE
United States United States Brands   FALSE TRUE
United States UnitedStates Brands    FALSE TRUE
United States United-States Brands   FALSE TRUE
Force         Air "Force" One        FALSE TRUE
Force         Air Force-One        FALSE TRUE
```

In the above example I'm working with below functions but not yet getting the desired result.

```js
Function ExactString(Text As String, Word As String) As Boolean
a = Module1.StripNonAlpha(Text)
b = Module1.StripNonAlpha(Word)
     'ExactString = " " & UCase(a) & " " Like "*[!A-Z]" & UCase(b) & "[!A-Z]*"
     If InStr(1, a, b, 1) Then
     ExactString = True
     Else
     ExactString = False
     End If
End Function
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Function StripNonAlpha(TextToReplace As String) As String
Dim ObjRegex As Object

Set ObjRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With ObjRegex
.Global = True
.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z\s]+"
StripNonAlpha = .Replace(Replace(TextToReplace, "-", Chr(32)), vbNullString)
StripNonAlpha = Module1.CleanSpace(StripNonAlpha)
End With
End Function
----------------------------------------------------------------
Function CleanSpace(ByVal strIn As String) As String
    strIn = Trim(strIn)

  ' // Replace all space pairings with single spaces
    Do While InStr(strIn, " ")
        strIn = Replace(strIn, " ", "")
        strIn = Replace(strIn, "  ", "")
    Loop

    CleanSpace = strIn
End Function
```

Is there any other way to achieve my target?

Comment: What is wrong with you current code??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent kindly check my example i cant get the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the REGEX in the second function to also allow numbers and to remove spaces, since that seems important for your case. You can remove the third function since it's redundant.

```
Function StripNonAlpha(TextToReplace As String) As String
    Dim ObjRegex As Object

    Set ObjRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With ObjRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+"
        StripNonAlpha = .Replace(TextToReplace, vbNullString)
    End With
End Function
```

You could also remove your first function since it can be easily handled by worksheet formulas, which should have less overhead. In your sheet, assuming Column A and Column B are the two you are comparing, then in Column C:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FIND(StripNonAlpha(A1),StripNonAlpha(B1))))
```

Comment: It looks like it should also strip spaces - e.g. case `UnitedStates Brands`... Why is the pattern not just `[^0-9a-zA-Z]` and then replace using that to `""`?

Comment: Thank you.. I thought I was going nuts wondering why spaces weren't getting replaced out of there too. My regex is rusty and I need more coffee. I've fixed it up with added instructions.

Comment: @JNevill your formu;a and regex works cool. However "=NOT(ISERROR(FIND(StripNonAlpha(A1),StripNonAlpha(B1))))" formula is a case sensitive. I want it as non case sensitive eg: Spiderman = SpiderMan

Comment: It's a little verbose, but you could convert them to lower case for the comparison `=NOT(ISERROR(FIND(StripNonAlpha(LOWER(A1)),StripNonAlpha(LOWER(B1)))))`

Comment: @JNevill Yes, That's awesome. I should have thought about it, thanks a lot :).